# ERROR VuforiaEngine.pdb unloaded.... Why?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia, unload

before starting i specify my english is not good "-"

So lets go :D
Actually i try to create a Mixed reality project.
My objective build with unity and Visual stuid in Hololens (first model).
I installed all librairies for that and i open a demo project.
But after build in unity i open the Project.sln in vs.
Visual load the project and open the debugmode.
In the hololens i can see the project and it start alone.
A few moments later in Visual i have a error "VuforiaEngine.pdb unload"
I cry because before this error my project working normally.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPa5x.png)

How to resolve that ?

Thank you,

Law <3